# php create a new object instance using a boolean

Tags: php, class

I'm having a difficult time googling an explanation of a line of php code in a script I'm modifying. It is doing the following, where $boolean is a variable set to true or false.

$var = new class($boolean);

What is the significance of the boolean? Thanks.

Comment: what is the constructor of the class?  If you look at that it will probably make sense as to what it is for.

Comment: Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Comment: @Charles, my question is not about a class per se, but about initializing a variable to an instance of a class. I believe using the tag object was appropriate.

Comment: I was actually referring to the `new` tag :)

Comment: @Charles, OK after reading your profile, I'll accept that. :D It only added meaning in context. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This line is creating an instance of `class` using it's constructor function which is just a function in a class that returns an object. `$boolean` is the argument to the constructor function `new` is a php keyword used for creating instances of classes and `$var` is the variable to store the returned object in.

Comment: Thanks. I could not find this syntax in the php docs. Not that it isn't there-- examples are shown under Constructors and Destructors. But without knowing the argument is passed to the constructor, it's not an easy syntax to look up or google.

Answer (score 1):

The variables passed into the class, will be used to initialize the workings. Without seeing the constructor, it's hard to say the significance of the initializing variables.

Answer (score -1):

In object oriented languages, when you define a class you create constructors.  The constructors are functions of the type ClassName() or ClassName(Parameters), and you use the `new` operator with these to create an instance of the class.

The default constructor is an empty one, i.e. no parameters.  But you can also create constructors that take parameters.  Those are typically used to initialize the member variables of the class.  So in your example, the boolean is a parameter to one of the constructors.  What exactly it means can only be determined either from the documentation or the code.

Here is an example (not PHP):

```
class SomeClass
{
     private int x;
      public SomeClass() { this.x = 5; }
     public SomeClass(int xx) { this.x = xx; }
}
```

The empty constructor sets the member x to 5.  The constructor with the parameter sets the member x to whatever was passed in.  To understand what your boolean is doing, you would have to look at the class definition and see what the constructor that takes in the boolean is doing with it.

Comment: -1, a dictionary definition -- especially a **blatantly** irrelevant dictionary definition -- in no way actually answers this question.

Comment: Geez Charles, you ding my question for the use of tags and then ding an answer that in my opinion did answer it (the 2nd sentence in the last paragraph). Why all the heavy-handedness?

Comment: @PeterNosko, while the last sentence does indeed answer the question, the rest of the information here is factually incorrect when it comes to PHP.  It includes a non-PHP code sample that demonstrates things that don't work in PHP, or do work but are not the way modern PHP should be written.  As you're new to the language, it's best that you get advice that is not just factual, but factual and correct.  The other answers did a much better job at giving you the advice you needed.